# Electrical Problem, or is there?

Tags: wiring, receptacle, circuit-breaker

Tonight I had a breaker that kept tripping. Recently I had a wiring issue on a different circuit and got that fixed, but now this circuit is tripping my breaker. I disconnected absolutely everything on the circuit and it would still trip after 10 minutes or so. I'd try to leave one thing on, the stove light, or plug an appliance in like a lamp, and 10 minutes it would trip.

I went through and looked at every outlet and everything looked good, but I disconnected and reconnected them just to be sure, and again, 10 minutes, it would trip. I figured I'd try it on a different breaker to see if it tripped it. The one in question controls my kitchen light, 2 sockets in my living room, and 2 in a back bedroom. I switched it with the master bedroom/bathroom. They are the same size 20A breaker and same brand.

Now my master bedroom is connected to the breaker that kept tripping. I have my TV, xbox, space heater, bathroom light, and bedroom light on. It's been an hour and hasn't tripped once.

On the circuit that could be bad, I now have the stove overhead light, a space heater, and the kitchen light on, and it has also not tripped again on the switched breaker when before in 10 mins it would trip every single time.

The breaker is working fine on more power to it from room, and the circuit is holding up fine on the breaker I switched it to that used to be for the master bedroom.

My question is: **Where in the world is my problem?**  (*I'm completely confused.*)

Comment: Does either or both breakers have a test button?

Comment: No, unfortunately neither does.

Comment: Picture of the breaker panel?

Comment: If you switch them back does it start breaking again?

Comment: Are these breakers getting warm at all?   What loads are plugged in when they trip?  We need to hear about any load which makes any amount of heat.

Comment: Yes, what loads are on the circuit in question, and are the breakers getting warm when thye trip?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys. I worked all day today and didn't have time to get on. So it worked fine throughout the night. At 530 my girlfriend got home and the breaker that may have been bad that I switched to the master bedroom hasn't tripped at all. Were running a TV, bedroom light, bathroom light, 2 cell phone chargers, an xbox, and a candle warmer on it. It works fine. However, the breaker that used to be for the master bedroom and is now on the problem circuit had tripped. She reset it at 530, and it just now tripped again at 930.

Comment: Now instead it ran for 4 hours instead of the previous 10 minute windows on the other breaker. Neither breaker was hot when it tripped. They were both cool to the touch. During the 4 hour interval, we had the stovetop light on and a space heater running for about 3 hours of the 4. It didn't flip whatsoever. However, when it flipped at 930, nothing was on period. The light was off and the space heater was unplugged. As we speak, there is nothing on the circuit whatsoever besides the minimal electric it puts out just for being there.

Comment: I want to also note that I just removed an outlet that I hadn't checked on the circuit. On the outlet it has 2 neutral wires and 2 hot wires under 1 screw apiece. The second screw holds a 3rd neutral and hot wire on each side respectively. This also includes 2 ground wires that are under the same screw. Could this he the root of my problem and I need to replace the outlet with one that has spaces for each hot and neutral wire separate as well as pigtail the ground wires to make 1 wire? The rest of the grounds in the house are pigtailed. I have no clue why this one isnt.

Comment: I forgot to state that when I first removed the outlet, only 1 ground wire was connected and the other wasn't. I put them both on now, but haven't flipped the breaker on in case this isn't safe.